# Dynamic column of images defined height preserving natural aspect ratio possible using just css?

Tags: css, image, flexbox

BLUF: I was wondering if it is possible reproduce the results in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sirkha/83q4tkbx/22/show) using just CSS. If so, is it supported in ie11?

I want to create a column (or a row) of images that show the whole image, preserve their natural aspect ratio and fit within a defined height (or width, for rows). Furthermore, I would like the container to end up with the width of the images. These will be used in reveal.js slides, eventually.

[screenshot of image column generated with linked jsfiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEQpO.png)

## javascript

```
function imageLoad () {
    var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("st-imagecol");
    for (var i =0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        var box = boxes[i]
        for (var j=0; j < box.childElementCount; j++) {
            image = box.children[j];
            var aspectRatio = image.naturalWidth/image.naturalHeight;
            image.style.flexGrow = 1/aspectRatio;
        }
        setWidth(box);
        window.addEventListener( "resize", function (){setWidth(box); return false;});
    }
}
function setWidth(box) {
    var image = box.firstElementChild
    var aspectRatio = image.naturalWidth/image.naturalHeight;
    //would prefer to change box.style.width but it doesn't work in iframe on jsfiddle
    // it does stand alone, though... weird
    // box.style.width = aspectRatio*image.height; 
    image.width = aspectRatio*image.height; 
}
```

## html

```
<body onload="imageLoad()">

<Section>
<div class="st-container-h st-available-parent">
    <div class="st-flex-v st-available">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <div class="st-overflow-auto">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
</p>
</div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <div class="st-imagecol">
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/800/430/cat?random=1" alt=" Cat 1" />
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/680/700/cat?random=2" alt=" Cat 2" />
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/720/470/cat?random=3" alt="Cat 3" />
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/600/600/cat?random=4" alt="Cat 4" />
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/413/618/cat?random=5" alt="Cat 5" />

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</Section>

</body>
```

## css

```
.st-container-h p, .st-container-h h3 {
    background-color: rgba( 0,0,0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 12px;
}

.st-available {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-grow: 1 !important; 
}

.st-container-h > .st-available, .st-flex-h > .st-available {
    width: 1px;
    height: auto;
}
.st-available> * {
    display: block!important;
    margin: 0!important;
}
.st-available-parent > * {
    flex-grow: 0;
}

.st-overflow-auto {
    overflow: auto;
}

/* 

.st-container-h {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 700px;
}

.st-flex-v {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
section {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 70vh;
}
.st-container-h {
    height: 100%;
}
.st-imagecol {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 650px;
}
.st-imagecol > * {
    height: 1px;
}
```